# How to delete email addresses from Google Forms reminder list?

Tags: google-forms

Google Forms sorts respondents into those who replied and those who need reminding. I sent a form to 100+ people and now find the list has diminished to 85. I no longer need a response from certain folks and want to delete them so they don't have to be reminded to respond.

How can I edit the email addresses that show up in the reminder list?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to edit the email list and remove people from it.

Google always recommend adding your voice to their feedback when these sorts of questions are raised. You can do this from any Google Forms form page by clicking on the question mark at the bottom right of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to delete the pending respondents' emails, but if you are done with the survey and have saved the results elsewhere, you can make a copy of the form, delete the original and rename the copy to your original name.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit in the email list before sending.

click send reminder then manually remove those addresses you don't want to include in the reminder. Unfortunately you have to do the same again each time and they will remain as having not responded.

Answer (score -1):

Select: Send reminder. erase All of the emails, then unselect the "collect email addresses" box, in the upper left corner and cancel, then the form is reset and ready to start again.